# Gnome 3 extensions resources

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I just installed gnome 3 and I added a few extensions, I noticed they are coded in JS but I don't fully understand how they work.

What I am really interested right now is learning how I could add a clickable icon at the left of this extension [bottom-panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/) (code: http://pastie.org/private/w1kkcrr1lr95ujepp0lxg)

Where can I learn how to do that?

Comment: Not exactly on point, but, most of the time, the bottom panel is reserved for Notifications, which you can create using the regular Gnome libraries. However, maybe check out gnome-shell-extension-systemMonitor, as it's the only one I know that adds anything to the bottom panel…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by mixing two extensions, [bottom-panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/) and [show-desktop-button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/), credits for the code goes to their respective creators.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uXSbC.png]

> extension.js : http://pastie.org/private/xilvfei4jbfebs2bdswlq
>
> stylesheet.css : http://pastie.org/private/ldarwadqnuqvl0stncfmsw